# Set not null attribute to a existing column

Tags: mysql, sql

I create my `borrowed` table that keeps `which users borrowed which books` records of a library application.

[image]

I forgot to set `not null` When i create `userID` and `bookID` fields,

how i can add this feature ti this two fields?

I try this but failed:

`Alter table borrowed set not null (userID,bookID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can add a costraint in an existing column with the command `MODIFY`:

```
ALTER TABLE borrowed MODIFY userID INT(11) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE borrowed MODIFY bookID INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the `CHANGE` syntax separated by comma for multiple columns

```
ALTER TABLE `borrowed` 
CHANGE `userID` `userID` INT(11)  NOT NULL, 
CHANGE `bookID` `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```